# How to download a file from firebase storage automaticly and not with the url - Javascript

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, download, google-cloud-storage

I get to the point where i get the link with ref.getDownloadURL(), but that gives me a link that if i click on it the file gets downloaded. The problem is that i want the file to be able to be downloaded without link clicks.

And the ref.getDownloadURL(), gives me an array with strange things and on "i:" it gives me the url:

B {a: 0, i: undefined, c: B, b: null, f: null, …}
a: 2
b: null
c: null
f: null
g: false
h: false
i: "link" <-----

code:

```
var storage = firebase.storage();
var storageRef = storage.ref();
const ref = firebase.storage().refFromURL('link');
console.log("LINK", ref.getDownloadURL());
```

I tried to do .subscribe() that i saw on documents but that didnt work.
Any help?

Answer (score 1):

The `getDownloadURL()` method needs to call to the server to determine the download URL. Because of this it can't immediately return the URL, but instead returns a promise of that URL.

This means you have to `await` to get the actual URL:

```
const ref = firebase.storage().refFromURL('link');
console.log("LINK", await ref.getDownloadURL());
```

If you can't use `await`, you can use `then()`:

```
const ref = firebase.storage().refFromURL('link');
ref.getDownloadURL().then(function(url) {
  console.log("LINK", url);
})
```

Also see:

- the documentation of [`Reference.getDownloadURL`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.Reference#getdownloadurl)
- the documentation on [downloading data via a URL](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files#download_data_via_url), which contains an expanded version of my second snippet